# Jvectormap - Set hover color for each region?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, maps, jvectormap

I'd like to set individual region *and* hover colors for the JVectorMap plugin, and leave regions without data the default white.

So far, I've stripped out the scale data and replaced it with color codes (as shown in the code below).  This is awesome, but I don't know how to also add in hover data.

If possible, I'd also like to add in data for document.body.style.cursor, so that I can turn off individual regions (where, for instance, the entity is blocked from doing trade), so that it doesn't appear to be an active link.

You'll also note I've got code to open a panel in there.  It's for displaying a full popup div with individualized content for each region I have data for.  It's inherited code, so to be honest I'm not sure how it works.

If I've forgotten anything, please let me know.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;   
    $('#map_custom').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',   
        backgroundColor : "#b8b8b8",
        regionStyle : {
            initial : {
                fill : "white",
                "fill-opacity" : 1,
                stroke : "none",
                "stroke-width" : 0,
                "stroke-opacity" : 1
            },
            hover : {
                "fill-opacity": 0.7,
            },
            selectedHover : {}
        },
        onRegionOver: function (event, code, region) {
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        },
        onRegionOut: function (element, code, region) {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";

        },  
        onRegionClick: function(event, code, region){   
            if (code == "CA") {window.location = 'CalRamic-distributors-Canada.html'}
                if (code == "US") {window.location = 'CalRamic-distributors-USA.html'}
                    if (code == "IE") {
                        $(".panel").hide("fast");
                        $("#ireland").show("slow");   
                        document.getElementById('test_data').innerHTML=code;
                    }
                    if (code == "GB") {
                        $(".panel").hide("fast");
                        $("#unitedkingdom").show("slow");     
                        document.getElementById('test_data').innerHTML=code;
                    }
                    if (code == "ES") {
                        $(".panel").hide("fast");
                        $("#spain").show("slow");     
                        document.getElementById('test_data').innerHTML=code;
                    }
                    if (code == "PT") {
                        $(".panel").hide("fast");
                        $("#portugal").show("slow");      
                        document.getElementById('test_data').innerHTML=code;
                    }
                    if (code == "IL") {
                        $(".panel").hide("fast");
                        $("#israel").show("slow");    
                        document.getElementById('test_data').innerHTML=code;
                    }   
        // I've got a LOT more countries in my code, but you don't need all of them
        else if (code){
            event.preventDefault();     
        }
    },      
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: sample_data
        }]
    }
});

  /* Close the Panel */
        $("body").click(function(e) {       
            if (e.target.id == "close" || $(e.target).parents("#close").size()) 
            {               
                 $(".panel").hide("slow");
            }
        });

})
```

Currently this code pulls the color data from the sample_data.js file, which is formatted like:

```
    var sample_data = {
      "CA": '#0071a4',
      "US": '#0071a4',
      "IE": '#0071a4',
      "GB": '#0071a4',
      "ES": '#0071a4',
    }
```

I have gotten pretty far for a novice thanks to the community here, but I've been asked to go farther with jvectormap than I ever have before.  And sadly, I'm only dangerous with this programming code, so I'm reaching out to the experts.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is only a suggestion, you should get rid of the crazy if logic, and make it a function that is generalized.

For example:

```
function panelHandler(element, hideSpeed, showSpeed){
  $('.panel').hide(hideSpeed);
  $(element).show(showSpeed);
  $('#test_data').innerHTML('code');
}

if (code == "IE") {
    panelHandler("#unitedKingdom", "slow", "fast");
}

if (code == "GB") {
   panelHandler("#spain", "slow", "fast");
}

etc...
```

As for your question, just attach the class settings you want accordingly. You then check it on the event, and execute it like so:

```
$('#selector').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Hopefully this helps. If you need something in more detail, then let me know, and I can help with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look this over!  I do have a few questions.  Do I need to fully remove the `onRegionClick: function(event, code, region){ ` part of the code, or does that remain?  and same on the onRegionOver: and onRegionOut: bits?

One final question, I'm not sure I understand the last bit of code and how to check it.  I can't find anywhere in the code where the regions are called specifically with any bit of CSS code, only some global classes that apply to all regions.  Is there any way to call the cursors and hover color using the sample_data instead?